# replace some code with blank space in php

Tags: php, file-handling

I want to change some code by replacing it with blank space in all php and other files in my project folder and sub folder files.
I have the following code.

```
if ($handle = @ opendir("for testing")) { 
    while (($entry = readdir($handle)) ) { 
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") { 
            $linecop = '/*god_mode_on*eval(test("ZXkViKSk7IA=="));*god_mode_off*/';   
            $homepage = file_get_contents($entry); 
            $string3=str_replace($linecop,'',$homepage); 
            $file = fopen($entry, "w") or exit("Unable to open file!"); 
            fwrite($file, $string3); 
            fclose($file); // 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
}
```

But this code only works for one file. How do I change all files?

Comment: here is code if ($handle = @ opendir("for testing")) 
    {
        while (($entry = readdir($handle)) )
        {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") 
            {
                $linecop = '/*god_mode_on*eval(test("ZXkViKSk7IA=="));*god_mode_off*/';
                $homepage = file_get_contents($entry);
                $string3=str_replace($linecop,'',$homepage);
                $file = fopen($entry, "w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
                fwrite($file, $string3);
                fclose($file);
          //  }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
function recursive_replace( $directory, $search, $replace ) {
  if ( ! is_dir( $directory ) ) return;
  foreach ( glob( $directory . '/*' ) as $file ) {
    if ( $file === '.' || $file === '..' ) continue;
    if ( is_dir( $file ) ) recursive_replace( $file, $search, $replace );
    $content = file_get_contents( $file );
    $content = str_replace( $search, $replace, $content );
    file_put_contents( $file, $content );
  }
}

recursive_replace('/your/file/path', '/*god_mode_on*eval(test("ZXkViKSk7IA=="));*god_mode_off*/', '');
```

if you want to recursively search and replace, you should think of a recursive function :) Also, glob()/file_X_contents() are much nicer functions to use for file and directory needs. code not tested but is damn close to what you're looking for in any case.

Comment: thanks above code is perfectly work for me thanks a lot ..thanks